# Proof of cartesian product being a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that this relation is correct (to prove of cartesian product being a set?).

$$
X \times Y \subset PP(X\cup Y)
$$
I know it is based on the Kuratowsi's definition of an ordered pair, which should be:
$$
(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}
$$

Comment: This literally requires only the effort of writing down the definition of subset, power set, and union.

Answer (score 0):

$$X \times Y = \{ (x,y): x\in X \text { & } y\in Y\}$$

Thus each element of $X\times Y $ is an ordered pair$$ (x,y) = \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\} $$

Note that $$\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\} \subseteq   P(X\cup Y)$$

Thus $$\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\} \in PP(X\cup Y)$$

Which means $$X \times Y \subset PP(X\cup Y)$$